# What are the fixed points of the arithmetic derivative over the non-negative integers?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, arithmetic-functions, fixed-points

I just watched [*When the derivative of a number is not zero -- The arithmetic derivative*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh1qbp7LpFU&ab_channel=MichaelPenn) by Michael Penn.

I like to explore things visually and computationally, so I found [this recursive implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76944/the-arithmetic-derivative) of the arithmetic derivative.

```
f=lambda n,p=2:+(n*n>1)and(n%p and f(n,p+1)or p*f(n/p)+n/p)
```

Taking a kind of graph theory approach, I constructed a directed graph of each integer i from 0 to 10000 where the nodes are the integers. Two integers i,j share an edge if j = f(i), where f is the arithmetic derivative.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)


f=lambda n,p=2:+(n*n>1)and(n%p and f(n,p+1)or p*f(n/p)+n/p)


g = nx.DiGraph()

rec_depth = []
for i in range(10001):
    print(i)
    try:
        g.add_edge(i, f(i))
    except RecursionError:
        print('Blargh!')
        rec_depth.append(i)
        continue

nx.draw(g, node_size=1)
plt.savefig('arithmetic_derivatives.pdf')
plt.close()
```

The original author of this code noted that often the recursion depth set in Python is exceeded by this function, so you may note that below I set the recursion limit to 10000 and created a list to accumulate any cases that were missed. With this recursion limit I found no exceptions. But if you wish to tinker with this code you may want to increase/decrease that limit.

Anyway, this plot below is the saved output. You can see four loops. We know from the basic properties that $0 = f(0)$ had to be one of them.

[image]

Computationally I found these fixed points:

```
>>> [i for i in g.edges() if i[0] == i[1]]
[(0, 0), (4, 4.0), (27, 27.0), (3125, 3125.0)]
```

[OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C4%2C27%2C3125&language=english&go=Search) did not show any results for this as a sequence.

What are the fixed points of the arithmetic derivative over the non-negative integers?

Comment: Btw, the arithmetic derivative is sign equivariant (i.e. an odd function) so $-f(a) = f(-a)$.

Comment: The next fixed point is $823543$, suggesting that this is https://oeis.org/A051674 (i.e. the $p_n^{p_n}$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime).

Comment: Weird, I thought I searched OEIS. But you found a sequence that matches. Maybe I used their search engine incorrectly.

Comment: Seemed to work. ```f(823543) ==
823543.0```

Comment: I'm on holiday and can't bring myself to think, but I checked up to 10000000 and failed to falsify the hypothesis "the fixed points are A051674".

Comment: I just checked 285311670611 and 302875106592253, and they also worked.

Comment: 827240261886336764177 is too large for my computer.

Comment: Because $f(p_n) = 1$ for the $n$th prime, I think a little algebra might do the trick.

Comment: Well, there are two questions, neither of which I wish to think about (although I'm quite happy to let Mathematica churn): "are there any other fixed points", and "are these all fixed points"; but I can tell you for free that the first 95 elements of A051674 are all fixed points.

Comment: Btw, [A003415](https://oeis.org/A003415) provides an iterative Python implementation that doesn't suffer from this recursion depth problem... although it didn't get f(827240261886336764177) = 827240261886336764177 so maybe there is something I am missing.

Comment: Tried using a different implementation and it is breaking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310085/what-is-wrong-with-this-implementation-of-the-arithmetic-derivative

Comment: Got a solution for the iterative implementation breaking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72310254/4348400).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I finally got around to turning my brain on.)

Any fixed point must be a prime power. Indeed, if $p \mid n$, then say $n = f(n) = f(pk)$; then $f(n) = p f(k) + k f(p) = p f(k) + k = pk$. Therefore $p f(k) = (p-1)k$, so $p \mid k$ or $f(k) = 0$ (i.e. $k=1$, which you can prove by induction). Inductively $n$ is a power of $p$.

Then just find $f(p^k)$ explicitly (by induction), and show that it's equal to $p^k$ iff $k$ is equal to $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I recalled from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh1qbp7LpFU&ab_channel=MichaelPenn) I mentioned in the question that Michael shows that the arithmetic derivative satisfies the power rule:

$$f(a^b) = ba^{b-1}$$

Well, if $a = b = p$ where $p$ is any prime, then

$$f(p^p) = pp^{p-1} = p^{p-1+1} = p^p$$

As Patrick pointed out in the comments of the original post, the sequence of primes to the power of themselves is [A051674](https://oeis.org/A051674) on OEIS.

Comment: Note that the arithmetic derivative does not have the familiar addition rule that ordinary derivatives have, which rules out lots of possibilities. But I am not sure if this answer cover **all** fixed points of $f$.